# HTML/CSS - Animated background sitting on top of elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am experimenting with a responsive template by adding additional features to the design.

I am trying to add an animated parallax background to the navigation.

http://www.stopcry.in/test/

The background is made up of 3 divs complimented by some jQuery. At this link the background divs are placed outside of the "sidebar" div appearing somewhat correct - the image cuts off short as you scroll down.

When placing the divs into the "sidebar" div it completely dominants it and elements of the sidebar disappear whilst leaving the logo in view and I cannot figure out why this is being singled out?

http://www.stopcry.in/test/index2.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post relevant code here and not on another site. External sites can change and make the post of no value to future visitors. For more information, see [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80978/1976560).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`. Note that while the background won't scroll with the page anymore, it will at least stay in the right place instead of cutting off.

If you need it to scroll with the page, you can try setting its height to the height of the page (make sure you update it if the window is resized), instead of what I said in the first paragraph, however note that there may be some jumpiness if you do this.

Comment: changing the position like you say results in no background image/animation displaying

Comment: That's strange, it worked just fine when I tried it. Are any error messages showing up in the console?

Comment: please confirm where you are reading position:absolute. no errors.

Comment: The three elements that make up the background have `position:absolute` defined on them. Changing that to `fixed` should work.

Comment: Changing those properties with the 3 background divs nested inside my sidebar div displays the same as the second link in the original post.. :S

Comment: I am trying to place the three elements inside my sidebar div. so the background only displays in this area. With the divs outside of the sidebar your solution works but is not what I need unfortunately ;_;